# Java How to achieve parallelism, dividing up work, dynamically?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multi-threading in Java.

My goal is to have one thread reading a file and then passing work chunks off to worker threads to process in parallel.

There is a really good example here.
[Concurrency Tutorial](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=247)

This code snippet takes a list of work (`ArrayList<String> URLs`) and dumps it onto a block of worker threads with function designated in the Task.call() method.

```
void pingAndReportEachWhenKnown()  throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException  {
  int numThreads = URLs.size() > 4 ? 4 : URLs.size(); //max 4 threads
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
  CompletionService<PingResult> compService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
  for(String url : URLs){
    Task task = new Task(url);
    compService.submit(task);
  }
  for(String url : URLs){
    Future<PingResult> future = compService.take();
    log(future.get());
  }
  executor.shutdown(); //always reclaim resources
}
```

This is exactly what I want to do, but I need a change.
The size of my work queue will not fit into working memory (HUGE file), so I need to buffer the read lines.  I can achieve Blocking I need with an ArrayBlockingQueue.  But then I need to also buffer the assignment of tasks to the CompletionService.  Work chunk size will vary, so completion time will vary as well.

How do I not put too much on the compService work queue? The following code would put the items on one at a time, because it would wait for completion before trying to get another task from the queue.  So this is insufficient.  What is the right or best way to handle this?

```
for(;;){
  Task task = arrayBlockingQueue.take();  //Blocking operation 
  compService.submit(task);
  Future<PingResult> future = compService.take();  //Blocking operation
  log(future.get());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads)` you can directly create a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  One of the constructors for that class allows you to provide the queue that the thread pool will use.

So, provide it with a bounded queue (e.g., an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a fixed capacity):  When the queue is full, your producer thread will be blocked, and it will stop reading the file until some of the work has been done.

---

John Vint said,

> That unfortunately won't work. Once the queue is full and all threads busy a RejectedExecutionException will be thrown.

What if you use this constructor?

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAX_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, TimeUnit...,
    new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(TASK_BACKLOG_LIMIT),
    new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()
    );
```

The javadoc for `ThreadPoolExecutor` talks about what happens when a task is *rejected* (e.g., because the queue is full).  It says that the *default* behavior is to throw `RejectedExecutionException`, but...

> ... Four predefined handler policies are provided ... (2) In `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`, the thread that invokes `execute` itself runs the task. This provides a simple feedback control mechanism that will slow down the rate that new tasks are submitted...

Comment: That unfortunately won't work. Once the queue is full and all threads busy a `RejectedExecutionException` will be thrown.

Comment: @JohnVint, Looks like there _is_ a way to throttle without having to build it yourself.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I like it, even if the queue is saturated you still make progress.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this before, you can use a BufferedReader and send a StringBuffer to the thread for processing after a set threshold of lines read.

Another options is to split the file into multiple smaller files. Sending each file to a thread once it has been created.

Here is an example of the splitting a large file into multiple smaller files for processing. The Splitter is a class which just grabs a set amount of lines from the larger file to be placed into the smaller file.

```
    private void execute() {

    File segFile;
    Splitter split = new Splitter(maxLines, file);

    while ((segFile = split.nextSegment()) != null) {

        String seg = segFile.getName().substring(segFile.getName().lastIndexOf("_")+1);

        Runnable thread;

        if (workflow.equals("Account")) {
            thread = new AccountThread(segFile);
        }
        else {
            thread = new CustomerThread(segFile);
        }

        pool.execute(thread);
    }
    pool.shutdown();

    while (!pool.isTerminated()) {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no compelling reason to differentiate work-producer and worker threads. Instead of using an ArrayBlockingQueue, you could simply make the read operation thread-safe.

```
public static class SynchronizedBufferedReader extends BufferedReader {
    public SynchronizedBufferedReader(final Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized String readLine() throws IOException {
        return super.readLine();
    }
}
```

Instead of tasks producing one result each, each Task can take the same Reader, and do work in a for-loop until `readLine` returns null. This way, you can create just as many Tasks as you have Threads, and all will remain busy.

Comment: This is a really compelling approach.  I think one detail may not have been clear -- a chunk may be 400,000 lines long, and it cannot be split apart.  Nevertheless, I think the idea is valid.  Instead of a readLine() method I simply write a readChunk() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're really looking for is a semaphore. You can acquire a resource and ensure the task will release it when done. That should give you the throttling you want.

If you use this with the `CompletableFuture` you should have a bit cleaner code.

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(NUMBER_OF_QUEUED_TASKS);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

for (String url : URLs) {
    semaphore.acquire(); // if there have been too many requests     
                         // queued wait until one is released

    CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(new Task(url), e)
        .thenAccept(this::log)
        .thenAccept((t) -> semaphore.relase(1));
}
e.shutdown();
...
public static class Task implements Supplier<PingResult> {
    @Override
    public PingResult get() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I see NUMBER_OF_QUEUED_TASKS - does this mean I need to know before I start reading the file how many chunks are in the file?  EDIT: I looked at Javadocs -- I think this is limit on the number of simultaneous tasks being run?  Would I want this to be equal to numThreads?

Comment: From what I understand of your problem is that you want to be able to queue up some tasks but not all of them since you may run out of memory. The `NUMBER_OF_QUEUED_TASKS` is the number of tasks that can fill the queue + the number of threads. If you instead want it only to be the number of threads then you can change the value to numThreads